# Return HashSet<T> from HashSet of generic type in generic function

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

I've got a `Dictionary<Type, HashSet<GenericType>>` which I use to hold my data in, and I am trying to make a function that returns one of those HashSets given the generic type `T : GenericType`.

Basically

```
Dictionary<Type, HashSet<GenericType>> data;

public HashSet<T> Get<T>() where T : GenericType
{
    var tp = typeof(T);
    //....check if its in the dictionary, fill if not....
    return data[tp];
}
```

This isn't valid of course. But I am having a very hard time figuring out what I should do instead.
I feel like returning `T` is optimal though, since you then can do something like this:

```
Get<Derived>().Where(x => x.DerivedProperty == someValue)
```

But the only thing I thought of was to create a new `HashSet<T>` **every time** `Get` is called, and then using a foreach-loop cast and add every item from the already existing HashSet in the Dictionary, but this feels like such a waste?

Another idea is to skip HashSet and use another (covariant?) collection. But since these collections will hold **lots** of data, maybe it isn't the best idea either.

So in short I am wondering what the best approach for this problem is.

### Update

So this is the structure I got. The type which contains `data` is a type of service in my code structure. It will via reflection be loaded and initialized at runtime. From there I later use a ServiceFactory of sorts to get that service.

```
public class foo : Service
{
    public Dictionary<Type, HashSet<BaseClass>> data = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<BaseClass>>();

    public T Get<T>() where T : BaseClass
    {
        var tp = typeof(T);

        if (!data.ContainsKey(tp))
        {
            data.Add(typeof(Derived), new HashSet<BaseClass>() { new Derived(), new Derived(), new Derived() });
        }

        return data[tp];//this wont compile.
    }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass
{
    public int ExampleVariable {get;set;}
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // some things in here.
    public void DoCommonStuff()
    {

    }
}

class program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var service = ServiceFactory.GetService<foo>();
        var collection = service.Get<Derived>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to return a covariant interface.

Comment: Please clarify: You got `Dictionary<Type, HashSet<GenericType>>` and you can already retrieve the specific `HashSet<GenericType>` from your `Dictionary` but are stuck at retrieving the `GenericType` from said `HashSet`. Correct?

Comment: Yes I can get a HashSet from a Dictionary without problems. Then I have a HashSet<GenericType>, which I can't return as a HashSet<T>

Comment: @Tokfrans Could you show me a bit more of the code. Basically how you defined the class where your `data` is declared in. Just remove everything from inside the class that is irrelevant to the issue. Because it might be really enough to just to specify the class as such `class Klass<TGenericType> : IKlass<out TGenericType> { .. }`.

Comment: @SvenM. I am unsure as to what you mean, though I've updated and tried to explain my situation.

Comment: @Tokfrans Thanks for adding the code. I think my proposed solution does not reflect the level of abstraction/complexity of your code. In my answer everything hinges on assigning the generic type to the class that defines the dictionary. In yours it's a bit different. I'll see if I can reconcile the both somehow.

Comment: Is there a connection between `T` and the elements of the set at `data[typeof(T)]`?

Comment: Yes. The **key** in the dictionary is also the type of the HashSet.

Comment: @Tokfrans as per  the comments of `SLaks` and `Lee` I also strongly believe there is either `[covariance or contravariance]`[¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))[²](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654055.aspx)[³](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654061.aspx)[⁴](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654058.aspx) involved here which needs to be correctly addressed. See the references for more help. You might need to establish a connection via a common interface specifying there the correct type of variance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just change the type of the dictionary, and cast inside your `Get` method. Definitely, definitely make your dictionary private though - then you can make sure that *only your code* (ideally only the `Get` method) can access it:

```
// Any data[typeof(Foo)] value will be a HashSet<Foo>. Only
// the Get method should access this dictionary.
private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> data = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

public HashSet<T> Get<T>() where T : GenericType
{
    var tp = typeof(T);
    object value;
    if (data.TryGetValue(tp, out value))
    {
        return (HashSet<T>) value;
    }

    var newSet = new HashSet<T>()
    // Populate newSet here
    data[tp] = newSet;
    return newSet;
}
```

I have a bit more discussion of a closely-related issue in a [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/10/08/mapping-from-a-type-to-an-instance-of-that-type/).

Comment: Yeah having the dictionary private will ensure that there won't be anything else in it - good thinking! Thank you for your help.

Comment: I deleted my proposed solution because it completely missed the mark and no point in confusing folks with that code. Truly clever thinking of Jon Skeet. Well he's the go to guy for tougher nuts to crack. ;)